# Is there an app for quickly toggling between different settings presets / profiles?

Tags: settings, app-widgets

I am aware of apps such as Power Toggles, Extended Controls etc.. All of there however allow you to toggle each setting as a separate entity. I was wondering if there is an app which allows you to save custom presets of settings and then quickly toggle between them. For example - home (wifi on, mobile data and gps off), car (wifi off, mobile data and gps on), mountain (wifi, mobile data off, gps on) etc..

Comment: We prefer questions that focus on solving a problem rather than finding an app. I suggest you [edit] your question to emphasize the former and de-emphasize the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `profile` in Google Play.

You'd find apps like:

- MyProfiles
- Quick Profiles
- etc

Those are not my recommendations. It's up to you to see which one works best for you.